# App won't install : CertPath not validated: null

Tags: android, keytool, jarsigner

I have written an Android app (target 3.2) using Eclipse 3.7, I tried to sign the App, but on the target machine, either the App won't install or it installed but doesn't run with "application is not installed" error. In debug mode the app works fine with the temporary certificate.

I checked the App with jarsigner and it has `CertPath not validated: null` errors.

I have also set the Manifest parameter debuggable and test only to false.

With the keytool I use the following command line -:

```
keytool -genkey -v -keystore vgpad.keystore -alias alias_name -sigalg SHA1withDSA -keyalg DSA -keysize 1024 -validity 10000
```

then for the Jarsigner

```
jarsigner -keystore D:\dev\Java\jdk1.7.0_02\bin\vgpad.keystore -sigalg SHA1withDSA -digestalg SHA1 -storepass puffin -keypass puffin  V-G-Pad.apk alias_name
```

I have used various different options and also tried from Eclipse, export signed app... still the same error. Any help would be welcome, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In fact I solved this using two actions,

1. resorting to the Java 1.6.0.30 JDK, I was using the 1.7 before, this solved the key and signing issues.
2. Ensured in the manifest I had only the android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE once, before the application tag

This was after using the adb logcat command to see the lancher issues :

> Permission Denial: starting Intent {.... } requires
> android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE

Answer (score 1):

Manifest must contain the minsdk version and maxsdkversion

There is another way to sign up the application.

Right Click on Project -->Select "Android Tools" Option --> "Export Signed Application Package"

in that select project --> create new .keystore file validity(years) = 50

later install that signed apk by using

command prompt from your device with following command

adb install yoursignedapk.apk

this signed apk will successfully install on your device

Comment: I added min/max/target versions to the manifest, I did create using  ADT and command line, both results still have the same error.